# Removing elements by class name

Tags: javascript

I have the code below to find elements with their class name:

```
// Get the element by their class name
var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');

// Now remove them

for (var i = 0; i < cur_columns.length; i++) {
      
}
```

Do I ***have*** to reference the parent or something? What's the best way to handle this?

Here is the JS:

```
var col_wrapper = document.getElementById("columns").getElementsByTagName("div");
var len = col_wrapper.length;

alert(len);

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (col_wrapper[i].className.toLowerCase() == "column") {
        col_wrapper[i].parentNode.removeChild(col_wrapper[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="columns" id="columns">
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows</div>
    <div name="columnClear" class="contentClear" id="columnClear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Using jQuery (which you really could be using in this case, I think), you could do this like so:

```
$('.column').remove();
```

Otherwise, you're going to need to use the parent of each element to remove it:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Answer (score 284):

If you prefer not to use JQuery:

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    while(elements.length > 0){
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering why he's removing the first element (index 0) always, it's because when you remove an element, it also shrinks the `elements` array.

Comment: what about the others indexes (accept the 0 index)?

Comment: @ofir_aghai as @JeffersonLima points the `getElementsByClassName` is a live collection. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Answer (score 88):

Use [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

### Remove single element

```js
document.querySelector("#remove").remove();
```

### Remove multiple elements

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

If you want a handy reusable function:

```js
const remove = (sel) => document.querySelectorAll(sel).forEach(el => el.remove());

// Use like:
remove(".remove");
remove("#remove-me");
```

```html
<p class="remove">REMOVE ME</p>
<p>KEEP ME</p>
<p class="remove">REMOVE ME</p>
<p id="remove-me">REMOVE ME</p>
```

Answer (score 61):

In pure vanilla Javascript, without jQuery or ES6, you could do:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");

while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
```

Comment: This one work on WordPress using Elementor page builder and adding a HTML element to add JavaScript without having to pay for the Pro version

Answer (score 34):

One line

```
document.querySelectorAll(".remove").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

For example you can do in this page to remove userinfo

```
document.querySelectorAll(".user-info").forEach(el => el.remove());
```

Answer (score 17):

This works for me

```
while (document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')[0]) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')[0].remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Brett - are you aware that [`getElementyByClassName`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements) support from IE 5.5 to 8 is [*not there* according to quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements)?. You would be better off following this pattern if you care about cross-browser compatibility:

- Get container element by ID.
- Get needed child elements by tag name.
- Iterate over children, test for matching className property.
- `elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i])` like the other guys said.

Quick example:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("td");
var len = cells.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(cells[i].className.toLowerCase() == "column") {
        cells[i].parentNode.removeChild(cells[i]);
    }
}
```

[**Here's a quick demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/AzyBf/)

EDIT: Here is the fixed version, specific to your markup:

```
var col_wrapper = document.getElementById("columns").getElementsByTagName("div");

var elementsToRemove = [];
for (var i = 0; i < col_wrapper.length; i++) {
    if (col_wrapper[i].className.toLowerCase() == "column") {
        elementsToRemove.push(col_wrapper[i]);
    }
}
for(var i = 0; i < elementsToRemove.length; i++) {
    elementsToRemove[i].parentNode.removeChild(elementsToRemove[i]);
}
```

The problem was my fault; when you remove an element from the resulting array of elements, the length changes, so one element gets skipped at each iteration. The solution is to store a reference to each element in a temporary array, then subsequently loop over those, removing each one from the DOM.

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6z6p/1/)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `forEach` over `for`/`while` looping. In order to use it's necessary to convert `HTMLCollection` to `Array` first:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("post-text"))
    .forEach(element => element.remove());
```

Pay attention, it's not necessary the most efficient way. Just much more elegant for me.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, one-liner, using ES6 spread operator due document.getElementByClassName returns a HTML collection.

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('dz-preview')].map(thumb => thumb.remove());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to remove from the parent:

```
cur_columns[i].parentNode.removeChild(cur_columns[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to remove elements which are added dynamically try this:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
    const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('your-class-name');
    while (elements.length > 0) elements[0].remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax: `node.parentNode`

For example:

```
someNode = document.getElementById("someId");
someNode.parentNode.removeChild(someNode);
```

Comment: This question asked to remove by className

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function might solve your problem like below

```
removeAllByClassName = function (className) {
    function findToRemove() {
        var sets = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        if (sets.length > 0) {
            sets[0].remove();
            findToRemove();
        }
    }
    findToRemove();
};
//
removeAllByClassName();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've completed a similar task in Pure JavaScript.

```js
function setup(item){
   document.querySelectorAll(".column") /* find all classes named column */
  .forEach((item) => { item /* loop  through each item */
      .addEventListener("click", (event) => { item
        /* add event listener for each item found */
          .remove(); /* remove self - changed node as needed */
      });
  });
  }

  setup();
```

```html
<div class="columns" id="columns">
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows1</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows2</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows3</div>
    <div class="column"><input type="checkbox" name="col_list[]" value="cows">cows4</div>
    <div name="columnClear" class="contentClear" id="columnClear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const elem= document.getElementsByClassName('column')

for (let i = elem.length; 0 < i ; )
    elem[--i].remove();
```

OR

```
const elem= document.getElementsByClassName('column')

while (elem.length > 0 )
    elem[0].remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

The skipping elements bug in this (code from above)

```
var len = cells.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(cells[i].className.toLowerCase() == "column") {
        cells[i].parentNode.removeChild(cells[i]);
    }
}
```

can be fixed by just running the loop backwards as follows (so that the temporary array is not needed)

```
var len = cells.length;
for(var i = len-1; i >-1; i--) {
    if(cells[i].className.toLowerCase() == "column") {
        cells[i].parentNode.removeChild(cells[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can you use a simple solution, just change the class, the HTML Collection filter is updated:

```
var cur_columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');

for (i in cur_columns) {
   cur_columns[i].className = '';
}
```

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html

Comment: This will not work since the array of the loop is modified inside the loop itself. The result is that the last element will be skipped.