# Remove specific value from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with an unknown amount of nesting. I just need to remove `<span class='highlight'>` and `</span>` from it.

How do I do that?

My idea was, to create a JSON string and replace the specific value with nothing, but somehow it doesn't work. Note: the specific value can exists more than once.

Here is my code for it:

```
function removeHighlightFromData(aData){

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(aData)
jsonData = jsonData.replace("<span class='highlight'>", "");
jsonData = jsonData.replace('<span class="highlight">', "");
jsonData = jsonData.replace("</span>", "");
return jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData);
```

}

Any idea what is wrong, or any other approaches?

Comment: A fiddle with some sample data will be good.

Comment: Can you give us an example of `aData`?

Comment: Well, you should avoid modifying dom via string manipulation. Also, this will remove all `</span>`'s whether or not it was associated with one of `class="highlight"`

Comment: You may be going the hard way at something. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Maybe you could turn it into HTML and then search for that class and remove it. That would do the same as replacing `<span class='highlight'>...</span>` with `<span>...</span>` which wouldn't be visible on the screen.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Comment: give me a minute, i will show you how aData looks like

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if your json has multiple occurrences of string you want to replace ? It might be that the first occurrence only is getting replaced because you are not using global switch.  Try :

```
jsonData = jsonData.replace(\<span class=\'highlight\'>/g, "");
```

&

```
jsonData = jsonData.replace(\/g, "");
```

to replace all occurrences.