# How can I stop HTML from rendering using Javascript in a JSP page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The idea is, if a user is accessing our site from China, we've got to block certain assets to improve our site speed. (For example, Facebook resources. I need to block them from even trying to load, because they'll always come back as blocked)

The caveat is that I have to do it in JavaScript *(update: see edit at bottom)*, because it must be done client-side due to our caching with Akamai.

Consider this HTML with some JSTL:

```
<div class="num1">
  //some stuff like text and images
    <div class="num2">
        //a nested div with other stuff
      <c:if test="${varIsAlwaysTrue eq false}">
        <div class="num3">
        </div>
      </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I put something like an IF statement around that, which uses a JavaScript variable? (The variable is called XY.isChina)

All I can really think of is what would be the scriptlet approach: (instead of the <% tags and Java code, obviously)

```
<script>
if (XY.isChina === false) {
</script>

<div class="num1">
  //some stuff like text and images
    <div class="num2">
        //a nested div with other stuff
      <c:if test="${varIsAlwaysTrue eq false}">
        <div class="num3">
        </div>
      </c:if>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
}
</script>
```

I'm almost positive that won't work.

The object of the game here is that none of that stuff within the IF statement loads. Making holes on the page is acceptable, but if it's possible for responsive elements to treat it like it's not even there (for alignment purposes) then that's even better.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I should have said that I need to do it client-side instead of specifying JavaScript in particular. The variable is already set in JavaScript, but if there are other client-side methods to doing this, that's fine. ***I cannot, however, use libraries like jQuery.***

Comment: Can you try the other way round: load them later via JS if its not China, else let it be?

Comment: actually js would be a bad idea if the user has js turned off

Comment: I agree that JS is a lesser idea, but our company had a discussion about this and we (rather defeatedly) decided to go with JS was we have so much other stuff going on, we can't rely on server-side processing for this.

Comment: Have you looked at maybe using the framework angular js. Make a template with all of your blocked resources and only load the template if they are not in China

Comment: @DeveshKhandelwal Yes, but our "default" case is that most of the time, these particular sites are not being hit from China. However if the idea you have makes that a moot point, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @Binvention Note my edit that I cannot use any additional libraries, which includes angular.

Comment: What you need to do is some how append your blocked div into the document after its checked if it is in China I know you can do it using Dom but I've never done it before

Comment: Or do the reverse and remove the blocked div from the document if you're in China

Comment: @Binvention Do you have any links to what you're talking about? Is Dom something I "natively" have access to?

Comment: @Binvention I take that back, I found a tutorial.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document it's part of the browser supported web api so it doesn't require external libraries and I don't know of anything that doesn't support it

Comment: @Binvention Excellent, thank you, it seems a combination of this method and simply hiding some links will be the way forward. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it the other way. Why don't you hide those sections if `XY.isChina == true` rather than not loading them if this condition is true since your JSP has already rendered the HTML before even Javascript is executed.

```
<script>
if (XY.isChina === false) {
   document.getElementById( "numxyz" ).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Comment: I came across this as an option earlier in my research. Just wondering: do I have to name every single element, or if I hide the first div, do the nested ones go away too?

Comment: @Joodoo Yes, unless they have a common class, which could easily be in your control. Then you can hide/remove by class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Comment: This would prevent them from showing but not from loading.

Comment: Well, to start with this is fine. I can just hide the Facebook stuff, and if they can't click on it, great. Some of our embedded stuff, like Google Maps, probably needs a different approach.

Comment: Wondering if adding that common class would screw up our CSS? If I just add "flibbityflobbityfloo" as an additional class, that's not mentioned anywhere in our CSS obviously. Would the CSS rules that have always worked continue to work? Would they still match? (I'm leaning towards "there's gonna be a problem with that"

Comment: @joodoo if the same class is not used anywhere else and is unlikely to be used anywhere else  then it should not be a problem.

Comment: @gurvinder372 great, thank you. I'll name it something foolish so no one else will use it :) It seems that a combination of your suggestions and using DOM as suggested above is the way forward.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer because what I ended up doing was most inspired by this answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> I need to block them from even trying to load

sounds like trying to square the circle, since also

> it must be done client-side due to our caching

So as a first (partial) conclusion it seems that you *must* accept the involved parts to be loaded.

Then the remaining problem is to avoid displaying what will be hidden just right (takes time, and bad for the user experience).

So the solution could be to originally hide these parts, then show them only if they must show. In your given example, looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="num1 block-for-china"> <!-- note the dedicated class here -->
  //some stuff like text and images
    <div class="num2">
        //a nested div with other stuff
      <c:if test="${varIsAlwaysTrue eq false}">
        <div class="num3">
        </div>
      </c:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block-for-china {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
document.onload(function() {
  if (!XY.isChina) { // <-- up to you how to test this condition...
    var blockForChina = document.getElementsByClassName('block-for-china');
    for (var index in blockForChina) {
       blockForChina[index].style.display = 'inherit';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this in a JS Fiddle right now, but my initial impressions: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I'll let you know if this is the key to my problems!

Comment: Query: the CSS seems to just display none no matter what. Is the JS supposed to toggle that?

Comment: As English is not my mother language I'm not absolutely sure to understand "no matter what"! But _a priori_ yes: the trick is 1) none is displayed just after loading; 2) the JS part toggles that **if you recognized the XY.China condition is false** (I proposed `inherit` in order to keep agnostic vs any involved component).

Comment: Sorry, instead of "no matter what" it could say "always." Thanks for the answer :)