# Trying to delete/remove a div from within an iframe using onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, onload

I'm trying to remove a few div tabs from within an iframe, using the onload function set within the iframe itself for simplicity of having everything in one location. Can't stress enough, as most seem to neglect the fact, I want to use the onload WITHIN this < iframe >

```
<iframe scrolling=no frameborder=0 src='insertwebsitehere' width=100% onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;" > #document </iframe>
```

The div tabs I want to remove don't have specific ids, but classes instead

1. `class="d2l-page-actions-container d2l-right"`
2. `class="d2l-action-buttons"`

I thought about adding something like this in the onload function;

```
<iframe onload="this.height=this.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;this.contentWindow.document.html.body.removeClass('insertclasshere');">
```

but it's not working, advice?

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066534/3088508

Comment: Able to elaborate on what I'm looking for in that, that would apply to my situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name)

Comment: 1. Identical answers.
2. Doesn't answer my question about using the onload function within the iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `onload`:

```
var elements = this.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll('.d2l-page-actions-container.d2l-right, .d2l-action-buttons');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
    elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]);
}
```

I can't test whether this'll work in your iframe, but it works in my test document:

```html
<body onload="var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.d2l-page-actions-container.d2l-right, .d2l-action-buttons'); for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(elements[i]); }">
    <div class="d2l-page-actions-container d2l-right">d2l-page-actions-container d2l-right</div>
    <div class="d2l-action-buttons">d2l-action-buttons</div>
    <div class="otherClass">otherClass</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding David. I tested it, but after inputting the lines in the iframe, the entire thing disappeared.

Second thought, is it possible to just use the 
this.contentWindow.document.querySelectorAll('text')
with the addition of a remove feature? I've tried stuff like this before, but none have worked, and I want to assume it does have 'this'='this.content.....' where this is removeClass or whatever

Comment: nvm, this works. Just had an error in my coding that I fixed. You're a life saver :) :P

Comment: Posting a few other questions if you could help?