# Trouble removing elements from html body using removeChild

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently wasting my time creating an app which draws certain objects on a html body using javascript. 
I've created some label panels which get drawn just as expected. They all belong to the same class "overlay messageBox".

There is a function which allows you to delete already drawn messageBoxes.

```
    var labelsHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay messageBoxName');
    try {
        var lenght = labelsHtml.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            labelsHtml[i].parentElement.removeChild(labelsHtml[i]);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
```

Note: `labelsHtml` count got the right value. There are 4 drawn boxes and the count = 4.

Problem: only two of four MessageBoxes get deleted and an exception is thrown:

> The parentElement property of an undefined or null reference can not
>   be retrieved.

Also i can retrieve the `innerHtml` of all entries when hardcoded so they are not null or undefinied. Am I missing something here?

Clearing the whole HTML body is no option, because it contains multible elements of other classes.

Comment: Post your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: only two of four MessageBoxes get deleted and an exception is
>   thrown:

`labelsHtml` is a live `NodeList`, hence when you remove the value from labelsHtml , its `length` property changes.

You can convert this an `Array` first

```
Array.from( labelsHtml ).forEach( item => item.parentNode.removeChild( item ) );
```

Comment: This makes sense as it's actually the first and 3rd that do get removed (ie the first and then second index after the first is removed. Then the 4th index is out of bounds. Nice.

Comment: Well, thank you! It works just fine and your explaination basically cleared the fog

Comment: Well done using the Array.from because it' s a live collection.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

using jQuery:

```
$('.myClass').remove()
```

using es6:

```
const removeElements = (elms) => Array.from(elms).forEach(el => el.remove());

// Use like:
removeElements( document.querySelectorAll(".remove") );
```

btw this is a duplicate:

[Removing elements by class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name)