# Delete all button in to do app

Tags: javascript, removechild

I try to add delete all to my to do app.
I have something like this:

```
function removeAll(){
        var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
        if(ol.lenght > 0){
            ol.remove();
        }
    }
document.getElementById('delete-all').addEventListener('click', removeAll);

<input type="text" id="text-field">
<input type="button" id="add-task" value="dodaj zadanie!">
<input type="button" id="delete-all" value="usuń wszystko">

<div id="to-do-list-container">
    <ul id="task-list">
        <ol>damian</ol>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And it show's no errors... I check if elements with tags ol exist, then try to remove ALL elements with ol tags. I tried with ol.parrentNode.remove(); and same effect...

Comment: `lenght` ?? is that a typo?

Comment: Aside from the typo, `<ol>` is not a valid child of `<ul>`

Comment: Oh... but now it's shows:
Uncaught TypeError: ol.remove is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.removeAll

Comment: I changed it for li (forgot to change it before...) - it's not vanilla js?

Comment: `ol` is a _node list_, it makes no sense to try and “remove” _that_. You need to loop over the elements contained in that node list, and then remove them individually. (And while doing so, you need to keep in mind that node lists are “live”.)

Comment: Probably a better dupe for this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following with `while` loop:

```js
function removeAll(){
  var list = document.getElementById("task-list");
  while(list.firstChild){
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
}
document.getElementById('delete-all').addEventListener('click', removeAll);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text-field"/>
<input type="button" id="add-task" value="dodaj zadanie!"/>
<input type="button" id="delete-all" value="usuń wszystko"/>

<div id="to-do-list-container">
    <ul id="task-list">
        <ol>damian</ol>
        <ol>damian2</ol>
        <ol>damian3</ol>
    </ul>
</div>
```