# Remove created elements with a classname DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have just finished everything in a project I'm working on, its a to do list where you add and remove items off the list.

Right now when I add a task to the list it created a element with a classname of "produkter"

I can remove each one separate by clicking on them but now I need to make it possible with this button to clear it all at once and what is wrong here?

This is the code where I try remove the objects:
(its the `removeelementsbyClass` variable and function) Shouldn't the function be activated as I click on it with my `addeventlistener` is set to click?

And in the function itself shouldn't that clear the list off all content?

```
var addProdukt = document.getElementById("newtodo");
var addProduktButton = document.getElementById("newtodobutton");
var errorMessage = document.getElementById("message");
var toDoList = document.getElementById("todolist");
var i;
var removeElementsByClass = document.getElementById("clearbutton");


// Händelsehanterare

addProdukt.addEventListener("keyup", checkInput, false);
addProduktButton.addEventListener("click", addProdukt1, false);
removeElementsByClass.addEventListener("click", removeElementsByClass, false);
window.onload = init;

function removeElementsByClass() {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

This is also a picture of how it looks on the page:

[image: https://gyazo.com/c918678d5d54b32430999e332469e728]

So basically everything is working in my code, its just to get the button to clear it all I need to fix.

And here is all the code btw:

```
//Kod skapad av Emil Palm
"use strict";

//Variabler

var addProdukt = document.getElementById("newtodo");
var addProduktButton = document.getElementById("newtodobutton");
var errorMessage = document.getElementById("message");
var toDoList = document.getElementById("todolist");
var i;
var removeElementsByClass = document.getElementById("clearbutton");


// Händelsehanterare

addProdukt.addEventListener("keyup", checkInput, false);
addProduktButton.addEventListener("click", addProdukt1, false);
removeElementsByClass.addEventListener("click", removeElementsByClass, false);
window.onload = init;

function removeElementsByClass() {
    localStorage.clear();
}

//Initieringsfunktion

function init() {
    console.log("Initierar...");

        //Läs in Produktlista

        loadProdukter();

// Inaktivera knappen

    addProduktButton.disabled = true;

}




// Kontrollera input

function checkInput() {
    console.log("Kontrollerar input...");

    var input = addProdukt.value;

    // Kontrollera längd

    if(input.length > 4) {

        errorMessage.innerHTML = "";
        addProduktButton.disabled = false;

    } else {
        errorMessage.innerHTML = "Måste innehålla minst 5 tecken";
        addProduktButton.disabled = true;
    }
}


// Lägg till produkt

function addProdukt1() {
    console.log("Lägger till Produkt...");
// Skapar nytt element
    var input = addProdukt.value;

    var newEl = document.createElement("article");
    var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(input);
    newEl.appendChild(newTextNode);
    newEl.className = "produkter";
// lägger till i lista
    toDoList.appendChild(newEl);


    newEl.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.target.remove();

        //lagra listan

        saveProdukter();

    })

    addProdukt.value = "";
    addProduktButton.disabled = true;



//Anropar lagring

saveProdukter();

}



// Spara produkter

function saveProdukter() {
    console.log("Lagrar produktlista...");

    var lagring = document.getElementsByClassName("produkter");

    var tempArr = [];

    //loopar listan
    for(i=0; i<lagring.length; i++) {
        tempArr.push(lagring[i].innerHTML);
    }


// konverterar till json sträng

var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(tempArr);

// Lagra i web storage

localStorage.setItem("produkter", jsonStr);

    console.log(tempArr);
}


//Läs in produkter

function loadProdukter() {
    console.log("Läser in Produktlista")

    // läs in och konvertera från json
    var produkter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("produkter"));


    //loopa igenom

    for(i=0; i<produkter.length; i++) {



        var newEl = document.createElement("article");
        var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(produkter[i]);
        newEl.appendChild(newTextNode);
        newEl.className = "produkter";
        // lägger till i lista
        toDoList.appendChild(newEl);

        // ta bort

        newEl.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.target.remove();

            //lagra listan

            saveProdukter();

        })
    }

    console.log(produkter);

}
```

If you need also the HTML here:

```
<body>
    <header id="mainheader">
        <div class="contain">
            <h1 id="logo">DT084G</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- /.contain -->
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Laboration 3 - DOM och events</h2>

        <h3>Lägg till ny sak att göra</h3>

        <section id="new">
            <label for="newtodo">Att göra:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="newtodo">&nbsp;
            <button class="btn" id="newtodobutton">Lägg till</button><br>
            <span id="message"></span>
        </section>

        <h3>Saker att göra</h3>
        <section id="todolist">
            
        </section>

        <button id="clearbutton" class="btn">Rensa</button>

        <footer>
            <p>Laborationsuppgift för kursen DT084G, Introduktion till programmering med JavaScript.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried other kinds of function but even tho its simple shouldnt that short line of code do the trick and clear the local storage and there by clearing the list?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Comment: I been on there, but I cant get it to work. Is my eventlistener correct? When i press the button it will activate a function called removeelementsbyclass?

Comment: I solved it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just always remove the first element.

```
var products = document.getElementsByClassName('produkter')
removeElementsByClass.addEventListener("click", remove_items, false);

function remove_items() {

for(let i = products.length; i>= 0; i--) {
    products[0].parentNode.removeChild(products[0])
}
localStorage.removeItem('produkter');

}
```