# Slike slider Hide/Show slide with custom class

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I use Slick Slider for my photo gallery. I would like to know if it is possible to deactivate slides and that these deactivated slides are not counted anymore.

Indeed I tried to use display none, although the slide is no longer displayed on the screen, it remains present in the HTML, see below:
[image: console]

I would like to display different images depending on whether we are in darkmode or lightmode (default).

Does anyone have an idea if it is possible?

---

[EDIT]
Now i use this slick filter function to filter my images. See Snippet for my HTML buttons and JS script.

```js
$('#slick-buttons button').bind('click', function(e){
var filter = $(this).val();
var key = "."+filter;

$('.slider-for, .slider-nav').slick('slickUnfilter');
$('.slider-for, .slider-nav').slick('slickFilter',key).slick('refresh');
$('.slider-for, .slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
});
```

```html
<div id="slick-buttons" class="slick-buttons toogle-switch">
        <button class="btn btn-default dark-button" value="dark">dark</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default light-button" value="light">light</button>
    </div>
```

At the moment the filter works but when you arrive on the page without having clicked on the day or night mode it displays all the images

I would like by default to display images with the light class only without click on buttons. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777077/removing-elements-by-class-name

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I looked at your link, and did. If I use .remove() I can't redisplay my slides without refreshing the page.
More precisely when :
- I arrive on my page -> Display only the slides with the class "light" only
- If I click on my "night mode" button once -> Show slides with class "dark" only
- If I click again on my "night mode" button -> Show slides with the "light" class only
With the .remove() function I can't switch from one mode to another without losing my slides.
Do you have any other advice for me?
Thanks